# How to find relations between the roots of a fourth degree polynomial which has only complex roots?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let f(x) is a fourth degree polynomial such that $f(x) = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. Let p be a root of f(x). Then which one of the following cannot be root of f(x):

1. $p^2$
2. $p^3$
3. $p^4$
4. $p^5$

I know f(x) has no real solutions and four complex solutions as given here

http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/x4-x3-x2-x-1-0-4-3-2-gt-exponents-could-anyone-205747

These solutions are very complicated and it is not possible to square or cube etc. each one to find which of the four options is correct. May someone help?

Comment: **Hint:** $f(x)$ divides $x^5-1$.

Comment: Ok the quotient comes as x-1 hence we can say the roots of this polynomial are 5th roots of unity other than one ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

In this case, as noted in the comments, the solutions of the $4-$degree equation are simple, since: $x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ so :

$
x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0 
$
for $x=e^{i2k\pi/5}$ with $k=1,2,3,4$, that are the four roots of $x^5-1=0$ different from $x=1$.

Comment: okay. so what should be the answer?

Comment: @RaghavSingal Have you given the hint any thought?

Comment: If only one of the possible answers is wrong than we must have  $p=e^{i2\pi/5}$ and $p^5$ is not a root.